# Error while Cashier login in odoo 10

Tags: authentication, odoo, odoo-10

I have create a new user with only "Point of sale user" right, and while I'm trying to login with the created account, this message will appear:

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: Did you checked the logs?

Comment: No, I'm new in odoo.

Comment: Try to find out the log file, check the parameters for the log file path.